# Column from pandas dataframe when called has keyerror

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a movie recommendation system using collaborative filtering and have created a list of the 10 most recommended movies with a pandas dataframe.

This is how I created it:

```
        movie_titles=pd.DataFrame(movieID)
        movie_titles.columns=['movieId', 'title', 'genres']
        df=pd.merge(df, movie_titles, on='movieId')
        ratings=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('title')['rating'].mean())
        ratings['num of ratings']=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('title')['rating'].count())
        moviemat=df.pivot_table(index='userId', columns='title', values='rating')
        movie_user_ratings=moviemat[movielens_title]
        similar_to_movie=moviemat.corrwith(movie_user_ratings)
        corr_movie=pd.DataFrame(similar_to_movie, columns=['Correlation'])
        corr_movie=corr_movie.join(ratings['num of ratings'])
        collab_ratings=corr_movie[corr_movie['num of ratings']>100][corr_movie['Correlation']<1].sort_values('Correlation',ascending=False).head(10)
```

My output is:

[image]

I am trying to extract the title column, but I keep getting a key  error. Could I have some help please?

Comment: That's not a column, that's the index. Try either `collab_ratings.index` or `collab_ratings.reset_index()['title']`

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it safe to assume title is the index while the columns are correlation and num of ratings?

Comment: You can check that yourself easily enough, `print(collab_ratings.columns)` and `print(collab_ratings.index)` and check the output

Comment: Just wanted to add, one of the tenets of python is "Explicit is better than implicit", so it's not really ever "safe to assume" anything like this without verifying the specific behavior you want